# Add image controls to toolbar via Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to add some button-like images (which when clicked will manipulate the data below) called update, delete and add column to the top right of the top toolbar. Again these would be images that would call forth events onclick.

Is this the best way to do that?

Would this be done via templates? Not quite sure I understand those yet. Are there other dependencies with templates?

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     columns: [{field: "patientName", title: "Patient Name"},
               {field: "MRN", title: "MRN"},
               {field: "account", title: "Account#"},
               {field: "dateOfBirth", title: "Date of Birth"}, 
               {field: "room", title: "Room"},
               {field: "bed", title: "Bed"},
               {field: "admitDate", title: "Admit Date" }],

     //toolbar: [
     //{"name": "create"}, 
     // {"name": "save"}, 
     //  {"name": "cancel"}
     // ],

     dataSource: {
       data:people
     },

     height:300,
     scrollable:true,
     pageable: true,
     pageSize: 2,
     sortable: true                
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`toolbar.template`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#toolbartemplate-string) and do something as:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns   : [
        {field: "patientName", title: "Patient Name"},
        {field: "MRN", title: "MRN"},
        {field: "account", title: "Account#"},
        {field: "dateOfBirth", title: "Date of Birth"},
        {field: "room", title: "Room"},
        {field: "bed", title: "Bed"},
        {field: "admitDate", title: "Admit Date" }
    ],
    toolbar   : [
        {"name": "create", template: "<img class='k-grid-add' src='add.png'/>"},
        {"name": "save", template: "<img class='k-grid-save-changes' src='save.png'/>"},
        {"name": "cancel", template: "<img class='k-grid-cancel-changes' src='cancel.png'/>"}
    ],
    dataSource: {
        data    : people,
        pageSize: 2
    },
    editable  : true,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable  : true,
    sortable  : true
});
```

The `class` values are important since this is what Kendo UI uses for binding the standard handlers to this image click event.

In addition `pageSize` needs to be define inside the `dataSource`.

For aligning the icons to the right you should define the following style:

```
#grid .k-toolbar {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Where `#grid` is the `id` of your grid.

See a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Y9vhE/ The only question is that since the images are not loaded you will see it as missing images but they are still fully functional.

Comment: sorry, but do I call toolbar.template or is that just a representation of the data below? just looking for how to implement in code. Also, if I want them all aligned right (next to each other) is there a way to call the style property on the "group" of buttons/images?

Comment: perfect. You're the best OnaBai!

Comment: Oops, one more question: the minute I added pageSize the grid disappeared. Further, what does pageSize actually refer to?

Comment: Um! Should not disappear. It refers to the number of rows displayed in the grid before start paging (take a look into the _running example_ that I refer in my answer and check for differences). As bonus :-) you might see that I have removed the `height`. It is the height of the grid space for rows. You might have lets say 10 rows while you have no space for seeing the 10 and then you have to scroll for seeing the rest.